# Mockito spy object, verify with any() as argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, verify

I have a simple unit test

```
Map<String, String> spyMap = spy(Map.class); 
spyMap.put("a", "A");
spyMap.put("b", "B");

InOrder inOrder = inOrder(spyMap);

inOrder.verify(spyMap).put(any(), any());
inOrder.verify(spyMap).put(any(), any());
```

But this throws an error. The following works:

```
inOrder.verify(spyMap).put("a", "A");
inOrder.verify(spyMap).put("b", "B");
```

So I can only test with exact string matches? That seems limiting to me. My test method actually generates a random String, so I do not know what exactly will be inserted into the map. I tried using `ArgumentCaptor` methods, but that did not work either.

```
Map<String, String> spyMap = spy(Map.class); 
spyMap.put("a", "A");
spyMap.put("b", "B");

ArgumentCaptor<String> arg1 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
ArgumentCaptor<String> arg2 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

verify(spyMap).put(arg1.capture(), arg2.capture());
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue here isn't the `any()` matcher, it's the fact that you call `put` twice and are trying to verify a single call. Instead, you should use the [`times`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.22/org/mockito/Mockito.html#times(int)) `VerificationMode`:

```
inOrder.verify(spyMap, times(2)).put(any(), any());
// Here ---------------^
```